# self upgrading own apk via net programmatically on android

Tags: android, apk

We have to port our software to android. One of the main feature of our software should be that the software can download a new version of itself from the net (our own server) and install it's new version too. All this thing should be done programmatically.

I'm new to android, so haven't got any clue how should it be done.

- How to create apk? - solved
- How to sign apk? - solved
- How to download apk? - solved
- How to copy the downloaded file overwriting /data/apk/my.software.name.apk? - unsolved
- How to restart the software by the running version? - unsolved

Comment: Iphone and Windows too :) We don't want to force the user to update, but this software is not allowed to go to the android market by the customer. So we have to solve the automatic upgrade such a way I described initatated by the user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> File file = new File(dir, "App.apk");
>
> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
>
> intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),
> "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
>
> startActivity(intent);

I had the same problem and after several attempts, it worked for me this way. Previously i got my new apk from a webservice.

Comment: I am using the above method for installing apk.. dose it also apply for upgrading it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do this. You just upload the new version of your program on the Android Market, and people see it right away. Users who checked the option "update automatically" for your program upgrade automatically without having to give explicit consent ; others see "upgrade available" and can just click 'upgrade' to upgrade to the new version of your program.

If for some reason you're thinking that you want to force the update on the user with or without their consent though, you just cannot do it. You can download the apk and should be able to hand it to the package manager, which in turn will ask the user to confirm whether they actually want to install it - and then again, for that you need the user to have checked the "allow unknown sources" option in development options, else the package manager will downright refuse to do it. But android will not let you install a new package without the user explicitly requesting it, or explicitly allowing auto-updates through the market.

If you have some backward compatibility issue of some sort and want to disallow running of deprecated versions of your application, you can embed in your application some logic that will check on your server for version information and terminate if it's outdated, with a message "this version is outdated, you need to upgrade to continue using this application" or something. But no upgrading in the back of the user.

Comment: The software is produced for a customer directly not for the android market. I've read about the package manager and the "allow unknown sources" thing too. For us informing the user and ask them to upgrade by pressing an "upgrade" button is accepted, but the question is:
How I can overwrite my old apk with the downloaded version while it is running and also has no rights to overwrite it?

Comment: Ah, in that case you can just hand the new APK to the package manager. This is done by launching an intent of type VIEW with the downloaded file URL (local one, file://sdcard/.../myfile.apk), which will invoke the handler for apk files, which is the package manager. You'll have a message "this application will replace an installed application, all previous user data will be saved" and the application will be terminated, then upgraded. It will have to be re-run by hand (re-running it automatically is possible by creating an auxiliary app, but quite complicated).

Comment: Anyhow, must it be downloaded onto a storagecard or could it be downloaded onto the device storage itself?

Comment: If there is any place on the phone where you have both the space and the right to write, I think it could also be downloaded on the device storage itself. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for inconvenience this is code and I also posted the XML permissions required to use it.

```
package com.SelfInstall01;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.SelfInstall01.SelfInstall01Activity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SelfInstall01Activity extends Activity 
{
    class PInfo {
        private String appname = "";
        private String pname = "";
        private String versionName = "";
        private int versionCode = 0;
        //private Drawable icon;
        /*private void prettyPrint() {
            //Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
        }*/
    }
    public int VersionCode;
    public String VersionName="";
    public String ApkName ;
    public String AppName ;
    public String BuildVersionPath="";
    public String urlpath ;
    public String PackageName;
    public String InstallAppPackageName;
    public String Text="";

    TextView tvApkStatus;
    Button btnCheckUpdates;
    TextView tvInstallVersion;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Text= "Old".toString();
        Text= "New".toString();


        ApkName = "SelfInstall01.apk";//"Test1.apk";// //"DownLoadOnSDcard_01.apk"; //      
        AppName = "SelfInstall01";//"Test1"; //

        BuildVersionPath = "http://10.0.2.2:82/Version.txt".toString();
        PackageName = "package:com.SelfInstall01".toString(); //"package:com.Test1".toString();
        urlpath = "http://10.0.2.2:82/"+ Text.toString()+"_Apk/" + ApkName.toString();

        tvApkStatus =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvApkStatus);
        tvApkStatus.setText(Text+" Apk Download.".toString());


        tvInstallVersion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInstallVersion);
        String temp = getInstallPackageVersionInfo(AppName.toString());
        tvInstallVersion.setText("" +temp.toString());

        btnCheckUpdates =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheckUpdates);
        btnCheckUpdates.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                GetVersionFromServer(BuildVersionPath); 

                if(checkInstalledApp(AppName.toString()) == true)
                {   
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application Found " + AppName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application Not Found. "+ AppName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
                }               
            }
        });

    }// On Create END.

    private Boolean checkInstalledApp(String appName){
        return getPackages(appName);    
    }

    // Get Information about Only Specific application which is Install on Device.
    public String getInstallPackageVersionInfo(String appName) 
    {
        String InstallVersion = "";     
        ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
        final int max = apps.size();
        for (int i=0; i<max; i++) 
        {
            //apps.get(i).prettyPrint();        
            if(apps.get(i).appname.toString().equals(appName.toString()))
            {
                InstallVersion = "Install Version Code: "+ apps.get(i).versionCode+
                    " Version Name: "+ apps.get(i).versionName.toString();
                break;
            }
        }

        return InstallVersion.toString();
    }
    private Boolean getPackages(String appName) 
    {
        Boolean isInstalled = false;
        ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
        final int max = apps.size();
        for (int i=0; i<max; i++) 
        {
            //apps.get(i).prettyPrint();

            if(apps.get(i).appname.toString().equals(appName.toString()))
            {
                /*if(apps.get(i).versionName.toString().contains(VersionName.toString()) == true &&
                        VersionCode == apps.get(i).versionCode)
                {
                    isInstalled = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Code Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    openMyDialog();
                }*/
                if(VersionCode <= apps.get(i).versionCode)
                {
                    isInstalled = true;

                    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Install Code is Less.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which)
                            {
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                //Yes button clicked
                                //SelfInstall01Activity.this.finish(); Close The App.

                                DownloadOnSDcard();
                                InstallApplication();
                                UnInstallApplication(PackageName.toString());

                                break;

                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage("New Apk Available..").setPositiveButton("Yes Proceed", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("No.", dialogClickListener).show();

                }    
                if(VersionCode > apps.get(i).versionCode)
                {
                    isInstalled = true;
                    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Install Code is better.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which)
                            {
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                //Yes button clicked
                                //SelfInstall01Activity.this.finish(); Close The App.

                                DownloadOnSDcard();
                                InstallApplication();
                                UnInstallApplication(PackageName.toString());

                                break;

                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage("NO need to Install.").setPositiveButton("Install Forcely", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel.", dialogClickListener).show();              
                }
            }
        }

        return isInstalled;
    }
    private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) 
    {       
        ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
        List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

        for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) 
        {
            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
            if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
                continue ;
            }
            PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
            newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
            newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
            newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
            //newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
            res.add(newInfo);
        }
        return res; 
    }


    public void UnInstallApplication(String packageName)// Specific package Name Uninstall.
    {
        //Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.CheckInstallApp");
        Uri packageURI = Uri.parse(packageName.toString());
        Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
        startActivity(uninstallIntent); 
    }
    public void InstallApplication()
    {   
        Uri packageURI = Uri.parse(PackageName.toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, packageURI);

//      Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED);

        //intent.setAction(Settings. ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS);

        intent.setDataAndType
        (Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"  + ApkName.toString())), 
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

        // Not open this Below Line Because..
        ////intent.setClass(this, Project02Activity.class); // This Line Call Activity Recursively its dangerous.

        startActivity(intent);  
    }
    public void GetVersionFromServer(String BuildVersionPath)
    {
        //this is the file you want to download from the remote server          
        //path ="http://10.0.2.2:82/Version.txt";
        //this is the name of the local file you will create
        // version.txt contain Version Code = 2; \n Version name = 2.1;             
        URL u;
        try {
            u = new URL(BuildVersionPath.toString());

            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();           
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HttpURLConnection Complete.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //that stops the reading after 1024 chars..
            //in.read(buffer); //  Read from Buffer.
            //baos.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.

            int len1 = 0;
            while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) != -1 ) 
            {               
                baos.write(buffer,0, len1); // Write Into ByteArrayOutputStream Buffer.
            }

            String temp = "";     
            String s = baos.toString();// baos.toString(); contain Version Code = 2; \n Version name = 2.1;

            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            {               
                i = s.indexOf("=") + 1; 
                while (s.charAt(i) == ' ') // Skip Spaces
                {
                    i++; // Move to Next.
                }
                while (s.charAt(i) != ';'&& (s.charAt(i) >= '0' && s.charAt(i) <= '9' || s.charAt(i) == '.'))
                {
                    temp = temp.toString().concat(Character.toString(s.charAt(i))) ;
                    i++;
                }
                //
                s = s.substring(i); // Move to Next to Process.!
                temp = temp + " "; // Separate w.r.t Space Version Code and Version Name.
            }
            String[] fields = temp.split(" ");// Make Array for Version Code and Version Name.

            VersionCode = Integer.parseInt(fields[0].toString());// .ToString() Return String Value.
            VersionName = fields[1].toString();

            baos.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error." + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error." + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            //return true;
    }// Method End.

    // Download On My Mobile SDCard or Emulator.
    public void DownloadOnSDcard()
    {
        try{
            URL url = new URL(urlpath.toString()); // Your given URL.

            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect(); // Connection Complete here.!

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HttpURLConnection complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
            File file = new File(PATH); // PATH = /mnt/sdcard/download/
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            File outputFile = new File(file, ApkName.toString());           
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SD Card Path: " + outputFile.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream(); // Get from Server and Catch In Input Stream Object.

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1); // Write In FileOutputStream.
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();//till here, it works fine - .apk is download to my sdcard in download file.
            // So please Check in DDMS tab and Select your Emulator.

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Complete on SD Card.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //download the APK to sdcard then fire the Intent.
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error! " +
                    e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi... I m doing as u said above.. but I m checking the version code successfully.. and new file is created in SDcard also.. but the size of apk is zero. so Parsing error occurs.