# Autoupdate an existing application in android through our own server

Tags: java, android, auto-update, android-install-apk

Myself trying to update an existing apk installed in my tablet through my own web server.Almost i have done with the help of google and stackoverflow.The thing i have struggeled is, i need to update an apk with alert dialog with single positive button like update.

I have used this peice of code from the link [self upgrading own apk via net programmatically on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987534/self-upgrading-own-apk-via-net-programmatically-on-android) which gives me an alert with both positive and neutral button like this picture [image]

My spec is that, i need to install an apk forcely with update button alone after downloading it from sever

Comment: Is that a dalog you created? As I think you refer to the application installation dialog from the system. It would be a major security issue if you would be able to change that, as the dialog also causes permissions to be granted by the user. If your application is a system application signed with the platform key, you can use other methods forcing apk updates. There would be serious security issues (as you could install Apps with any permission) if that would be possible for non-system apps.

Comment: @dst yeah dude, i knew that user should know abt permission's before installing but this application is going to be used within corporate so the permissions are same as installed application.